# javascript .search does not return value after &v=

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

the test variable is a YouTube link from which I am trying to extract `pa14VNsdSYM`

```
var test = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=pa14VNsdSYM";
var urll = (test.search(/[?&;]v=([^&;]+)/) || [])[1];
document.write(''+urll+'');
```

but I am only getting `undefined` http://jsfiddle.net/ZGjDb/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:
You should use `match` instead of `search`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ZGjDb/17/

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out sorry guys but if your'e wondering it's here http://jsfiddle.net/ZGjDb/16/ , REALLY and TRULY sorry users.

Answer (score 0):

use `test.match()` instead of `test.search()`